# Zoom on multiple areas in d3.js

Tags: svg, d3.js, zooming, geojson

I'm planning to have a geoJSON map inside my svg alongside other svg elements. I would like to be able to zoom (zoom+pan) in the map and keep the map in the same location with a bounding box. I can accomplish this by using a clipPath to keep the map within a rectangular area. The problem is that I also want to enable zooming and panning on my entire svg. If I do d3.select("svg").call(myzoom); this overrides any zoom I applied to my map. How can I apply zoom to both my entire svg and to my map? That is, I want to be able to zoom+pan on my map when my mouse is in the map's bounding box, and when the mouse is outside the bounding box, zoom+pan on the entire svg.

Here's example code: http://bl.ocks.org/nuernber/aeaac0e8edcf7ca93ade.

```
<svg id="svg" width="640" height="480" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" version="1.1">
  <defs>
    <clipPath id="rectClip">
      <rect x="150" y="25" width="400" height="400" style="stroke: gray; fill: none;"/>
    </clipPath>
  </defs>
  <g id="outer_group">
    <circle cx="100" cy="50" r="40" stroke="black" stroke-width="2" fill="red" />
    <g id="svg_map" style="clip-path: url(#rectClip);">
    </g>
  </g>
</svg><br/>
<script type="text/javascript">
  var svg = d3.select("#svg_map");
  var mapGroup = svg.append("g");
  var projection = d3.geo.mercator();
  var path = d3.geo.path().projection(projection);

  var zoom = d3.behavior.zoom()
      .translate(projection.translate())
      .scale(projection.scale())
      .on("zoom", zoomed);
  mapGroup.call(zoom);

  var pan = d3.behavior.zoom()
      .on("zoom", panned);
  d3.select("svg").call(pan);

  mapGroup.attr("transform", "translate(200,0) scale(2,2)");
  d3.json("ne_110m_admin_0_countries/ne_110m_admin_0_countries.geojson", function(collection) {
      mapGroup.selectAll("path").data(collection.features)
        .enter().append("path")
        .attr("d", path)
        .attr("id", function(d) { return d.properties.name.replace(/\s+/g, "")})
        .style("fill", "gray").style("stroke", "white").style("stroke-width",1);
    }
  );

  function panned() {
    var x = d3.event.translate[0];
    var y = d3.event.translate[1];
    d3.select("#outer_group").attr("transform", "translate("+x+","+y+") scale(" + d3.event.scale + ")");
  }

  function zoomed() {
    previousScale = d3.event.scale;
    projection.translate(d3.event.translate).scale(d3.event.scale);
    translationOffset = d3.event.translate;
    mapGroup.selectAll("path").attr("d", path);
  }
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

You need two `zoom` behaviours for that. The first one would be attached to the SVG and the second one to the map. In the zoom handlers you would have to take care of taking the appropriate action for each.

Comment: I edited my post above to show my code. It doesn't seem like using two zoom behaviors works correctly. Zooming gets applied to both the svg and the map (group). But panning doesn't work on the map. Furthermore, I want to not apply zooming whenever the mouse is over the map.

Comment: Have you tried applying `pan` to `#outer_group` instead of the whole SVG? How does panning the map not work?

Comment: Applying pan to #outer_group has strange behavior. The map does not pan at all, but it does zoom.

Comment: Yes, if I turn off zoom for the svg. Here's a better link: http://bl.ocks.org/nuernber/aeaac0e8edcf7ca93ade

Comment: Hmmm, it looks to me like having a separate map and SVG would be easier.